# ping an output within if loop

Tags: bash, ping

Using the script below I want to be able to get the IP address that is outputted at the end of it and then ping it.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter server number:"
read userinput

lookupip="d $userinput"

if [[ $userinput -lt 0 || $userinput -gt 9999 ]] #checks that the input is within the desired range
 then
   echo "Input outside acceptable range."
 else

#grep gets just the IP address

$lookupip | grep -E -o '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' | sed '1 ! d'
```

I can't figure out how to do this with the output:

```
> or >> filename | xargs ping
```

as using " or ` around the grep command (or putting it in a variable like so:

```
ipgrep=$(grepcommand)
ipgrep=`grepcommand`
```

or variables doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you post some errors? if possible append '-x' to your shebang line and post the output. ( -x adds debug output )

Comment: Nevermind XD I've just realised I can just do | xargs ping after the grep and that works. Sorry about that.

I would still like to know how to format it by putting the grep in a variable.

Comment: it should work as you've done it  ipgrep=$(grepcmd); ping $ipgrep. if you've fixed the issue please answer your question for others looking on SO. Thanks

Comment: As I did it incorrectly last time, what's the proper way to post the fix/answer?

Comment: just need to post the answer below in the your answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Derp, I only had to add:

```
| xargs ping -c 1
```

after:

```
sed '1 ! d'
```